# openfire debug log

Tags: openfire

I install Openfire 3.8.1 by extracting the tar archive to my Ubuntu 11.04.

I use the code at https://github.com/fritzy/SleekXMPP/blob/develop/examples/register_account.py to perform inband registration and get HTTP 500 error.

In order to further investigate the error, I check the `logs` directory in the extracted folder from the tar archive. I only found two files: stderror.log and stdoutt.log

In stderror.log:
    Server halted

In stdoutt.log:

Openfire 3.8.1 [Apr 7, 2013 8:43:15 PM]
Admin console listening at:

```
http://mymachine:9090
https://mymachine:9090
```

It seems there is no logs related to the HTTP 500 error.

I also have tried to enable the Debug log via Server-> Server Manager -> Logs -> Log Viewer -> Debug -> Debug Log -> Enabled in the admin console and reproduced the HTTP 500 error again. Nevertheless, there is no log related to the HTTP 500 error.

How or where can I find out the logs?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with Openfire, see the bug report here:
[Openfire is turning off debugging mode on startup](http://issues.igniterealtime.org/browse/OF-429)